# ST_ValueCount() returning multiple rows of same VALUE

Tags: postgresql, postgis-2.3

I want to calculate the proportion of each pixel value in a raster after clipping a much larger raster to my area of interest. However, after clipping and saving the raster from PostgreSQL database/PostGIS, the table created does not calculate the pixel number or proportion as expected.

**Step 1**: clip larger raster (Minnesota gridded soils) based on extent of "plotbounds" (polygon geometry table):

```
CREATE TABLE out.eonr_gaylord_2012_soils AS
SELECT ST_Clip(rast, p.geom)
FROM gssurgo_mn.mapunitraster_mn_10m, temp.eonr_gaylord_2012_plotbounds_data AS p 
WHERE ST_Intersects(p.geom, rast);
```

**Step 2**: Calculate the proportion of each pixel

```
SELECT DISTINCT pvc.VALUE, SUM(pvc.COUNT) AS tot_pix, 100 * SUM(pvc.COUNT) / SUM(SUM(pvc.COUNT)) OVER () AS prop
FROM out.eonr_gaylord_2012_soils, ST_ValueCount(rast, 1) AS pvc
GROUP BY pvc.VALUE, pvc.COUNT
ORDER BY pvc.VALUE
```

Output:
[image: Proportion of pixels incorrect]

**Why are there multiple rows (6) for each value?**

I can load this raster into QGIS and it displays fine. I tried exporting to my local hard drive as a geotiff (from QGIS), then reloaded into PostgreSQL using `raster2pgsql` in the command prompt, and ran the same query to calculate pixel number and proportion (with the imported geotiff raster), and it calculates as expected:

[image: Proportion of pixels correct]

When looking at the Info from QGIS DB Manager, the original raster (the one that doesn't behave as expected) has a few differences from the imported raster (the one that works):

1. Pages: 3 vs 1
2. Rows: 128 vs 1
3. Spatial ref: [none] vs "WGS 84 / UTM zone 15N (32615)"
4. Constraints: [none] vs many (e.g., enforce_max_extent_rast, enforce_out_db_rast, etc.)

Version info:

```
SELECT version()
```

PostgreSQL 9.5.10, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit

```
SELECT PostGIS_full_version()
```

POSTGIS="2.3.5 r16110" GEOS="3.6.2-CAPI-1.10.2 4d2925d" PROJ="Rel. 4.9.3, 15 August 2016" GDAL="GDAL 2.2.2, released 2017/09/15" LIBXML="2.7.8" LIBJSON="0.12" RASTER

Comment: Is your raster tiled?  In that case, you'd get a value per tile unless you used a union statement on the tiles, e.g. `ST_ValueCount(ST_Union(rast), 1)`

Comment: @John Yes, it is. The union statement ends up working for me, although I do get an error saying "aggregate functions are not allowed in functions in FROM" if I use `ST_ValueCount(ST_Union(rast), 1)` in the FROM statement. This hint helped me find the solution to my problem though - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because my raster was tiled, it resulted in a calculation for each individual tile (thanks for the hint @John). Therefore, I can modify the query in **Step 2** to achieve the desired result:

```
SELECT (pvc.valcount).VALUE, (pvc.valcount).COUNT AS tot_pix, (100.0 * (pvc.valcount).COUNT / SUM((pvc.valcount).COUNT) OVER ()) AS prop
FROM(
    SELECT (ST_ValueCount(rast_u.rast, 1)) AS valcount
    FROM (
        SELECT ST_Union(rast) AS rast
        FROM out.eonr_gaylord_2012_soils) AS rast_u) pvc
```

[image: postgis union query]